# reading a non-standard size binary long

Tags: python, struct

I have a very specific binary file structure that I would like to read into python. I've used the struct module successfully in the past to do so. Recently, I created a large number of these files on a 64bit architecture (my usual one is 32). I used C++ and write an unsigned long to a binary stream (which is 8 byte on that system), however, the standard size on my system for unsigned longs is 4 byte.

Is there a way to tell struct to read 8 bytes instead of 4 into one long?

Answer (score 4):

Check out http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#format-characters

This basically shows you that you'll have to say it's a `long long` and it will work.